# add date picker calendar to right tab in tiddlywiki 5

Tags: tiddlywiki5

very simple question but no success so far. No official help page, no google link.

How to add a calendar/date picker plugin to right tab in Tiddlywiki version 5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag & drop this plugin http://simplecalendar.tiddlyspot.com/

Comment: but how to keep it sticky above buttons?